# Show that $\{E\cap B\mid B\ borel\}=\sigma (\{O\cap A\mid O\ open\}).$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I have a problem to show that $$\{E\cap B\mid B\ borel\}=\sigma (\{O\cap E\mid O\ open\}).$$

What I did is : Let $A\in \{E\cap B\mid B\ borel\}$. Then, $A=E\cap B$ for a certain borel $B$. Since a borelien is a (at most countable) union for open, we have that $B=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N}O_i$ where $O_i$ open. Therefore $A=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N}E\cap O_i\in \sigma (\{E\cap O\mid O\ open\}).$

For the converse inclusion, I wanted to do as following. Let $A\in \sigma (\{O\cap E\mid O\ open\})$. I thought that it mean that $A=\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N}E\cap O_i$ for some $E\cap O_i$, but I heard that it doesn't mean this. So what does it mean ?

For example, I know that the field of borel set is the field generated by the open. Then all element of this field can be written as $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i$ where $O_i$ open, no ? But here isn't it the field generated by $O\cap E$ ? i.e. can be written as $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i\cap E$ ?

Answer (score 1):

To prove that $\{E\cap B\mid B\ borel\}=\sigma (\{O\cap A\mid O\cap E\}$ you must prove first that $\{E\cap B\mid B\ borel\}$ is indeed a field (otherwise inclusion or equality has no sense).

Then, if $\mathcal A$ is a set, the $\sigma (\mathcal A)$ is the field generated by $\mathcal A$. This doesn't mean that elements of $\sigma (\mathcal A)$ are countable union of element of $\mathcal A$ ! It mean that

1) $A^c\in \sigma (\mathcal A)$ whenever $A\in\mathcal A$.

2) $\emptyset$ and the set on which you defined your field is in $\sigma (\mathcal A)$

3) $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i\in \mathcal A$ for all $A_i\in \mathcal A$.

For the borel, it's not true that if $B$ borel, then $B=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i$ for opens $O_i$ (for example $B=\{0\}$ is borel which is not open). The only thing you can say it's that $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty O_i$ for $O_i$ open is borel.

**Let prove your claim**

I think that $\mathcal A:=\{E\cap B\mid B\ borel\}$ is defined on $E$. It's clear that $E$ and $\emptyset$ are in $\mathcal A$ since $E=E\cap \mathbb R$ and $\emptyset=E\cap\emptyset$. Let $A\in \mathcal A$, i.e. there is $B$ borelien s.t. $A=E\cap B$. Then, $A^c=E^c\cup B^c.$
Remember, we are in $E$, then $E^c=\emptyset$ and thus $A^c=E\cap B^c$. Since $B^c$ is borel, $A^c$ in $\mathcal A$.

Finally, if $A_i=E\cap B_i$ for $i\in\mathbb N$, since $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb N}B_i$ is borel, the claim follow.

The fact that $\sigma (\{O\cap E\mid O\ open\})\subset \{B\cap E\mid B\ borel\}$ is obvious since an open is borel. I let your do the last inclusion.